# Can't get @font-face with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I'm having trouble getting my client's custom font face to show up in IE8. It shows up in IE 9 & 7, and Chrome obv. I'm not sure why this one version of IE would be causing trouble. Here is my include statement in my html

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/ie/cherokee_ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

And here is the cherokee_ie.css file

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'cherokee';
src: url('../../custom.eot');
src: url('../../custom.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
src: local('☺'), url('../../font/custom.woff') format('woff'), url('../../font/custom.ttf')             format('truetype'), url('../../font/custom.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

h1 ul li {
  font-family:cherokee;
}
```

I'm not really sure what the smiley face on src: local is doing, but I found this code in another S.O. question that made it work perfectly in IE7 (or at least as far as I can see through BrowserLab.)

Also, is there a faster way to generate views than Browserlab?

Comment: As for the smiley: it stops Internet Explorer from reading the rest of that value and trying to use the other types of fonts and their `format()`s, which it doesn't support.

Comment: Oh, neat. I didn't know you could do that. Is that special to that special character, or can you do that with any empty character?

Comment: Anything will work - the trick is that IE doesn't support `local()` at all. The reason uncommon characters are used is to stop actual local fonts from being accessed, which can sometimes result in security issues. [This article](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) has some more information.

Comment: Are you sure your IE conditional is necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the IE Conditional and put this in your CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'cherokee';
    src: url('../../custom.eot');
    src: url('../../custom.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../font/custom.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../font/custom.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../font/custom.svg#cherokee') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

also use '...' for custom font-face fonts like so

```
h1 ul li {
  font: 18px/27px 'cherokee', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Also check whether your paths are set correctly.