# Custom font sometimes renders in italics in IE8 / IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, font-face, italic

In IE7 and IE8, when using a custom web font, text is sometimes rendered in italics, even when I explicitly set `font-style: normal`. The issue is sporadic - it will render fine a few times, then I refresh and everything is in italics, then I refresh and it's back to normal.

I'm using this `@font-face` declaration:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DIN';
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb.eot');
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/DINWeb.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DIN';
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb-Bold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/DINWeb-Bold.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DIN';
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb-Ita.eot');
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb-Ita.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/DINWeb-Ita.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DIN';
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb-BoldIta.eot');
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb-BoldIta.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/DINWeb-BoldIta.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Theres [a comment](http://paulirish.com/2010/font-face-gotchas/#comment-111554) on [this article](http://paulirish.com/2010/font-face-gotchas/) that indicates it could be about the order of the `@font-face` declarations: however the only thing that stopped the problem was removing the italic declarations altogether.

[Another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11029236) suggests using the Font Squirrel @font-face generator; I'm not able to do this however as the web font files I'm using have DRM.

Is there a way to solve this without completely removing the italic declarations?

**UPDATE:** Upon further investigation, it seems this issue affects IE8 as well, not just in compatibility mode.

Comment: You did not provide your HTML that's in use. Try to use unique `@font-face` family names. Example: `DINnormal, DINbold, DINitalic, DINboldItalic`. View CSS and HTML example in this [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10273361/1195891). If creating unique names solves your issue, I will make an Answer. Cheers!

Comment: @arttronics thanks, turns out unique font family names did end up solving the problem. If you write up an answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: Adam Sharp, glad that works out for you... I've posted an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For each of your `@font-face` `font-family` names, create a custom name instead.

Example:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DINnormal';
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb.eot');
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/DINWeb.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DINbold';
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb-Bold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/DINWeb-Bold.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DINitalic';
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb-Ita.eot');
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb-Ita.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/DINWeb-Ita.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DINboldItalic';
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb-BoldIta.eot');
    src: url('fonts/DINWeb-BoldIta.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/DINWeb-BoldIta.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

After those CSS rules are defined, then you can include specific CSS rule:

```
li {
  font: 18px/27px 'DINnormal', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If, like me, you came across this question while experiencing a similar issue using TypeKit fonts, [this entry from the TypeKit blog](http://blog.typekit.com/2011/06/27/new-from-typekit-variation-specific-font-family-names-in-ie-6-8/) explains how you can force unique `font-family` names for each weight & style of a TypeKit font to address it.

Comment: I can second this. I came across this comment and it helped me fix the issues i was having whilst using Typekit. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, web font was showing in Italic when using IE8(Emulator), after digging and digging I came across a article that suggest emulator can sometimes be misleading especially when it comes to webFonts, and what it suggested was trying the site in the actual IE8, as I am using a windows 7 machine i wasn't able to download the real thing so I used this site called http://www.browserstack.com/ (No testers or fake browsers. Test in real browsers including Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 and 11.)

and i noticed my font was not italic anymore :D

Here's the link to the article i read,

http://blog.typekit.com/2013/03/14/the-dangers-of-cross-browser-testing-with-ie9s-browser-modes/

Hope this helps you guys, if i came across something like this when researching it really would have saved me a few hours